# iterate through textboxes

Tags: javascript

I have text boxes where id for these boxes are from 1 to 20. These boxes are created in PHP for loop. 
How can i check using javascript if these textboxes are empty. and throw an error on each box.

```
foreach(i = 0, i<20, i++)
{
<input type = "Text" id="q_i">
}
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you put a class attribute on each textbox that was the same for all of the textboxes you want to iterate through.

Comment: i've updated my reponse, take a look, the before thing was adding multiple messages, not cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery?

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){if ($(this).val() == '') alert("Your Message Here");});
```

or, if there are other inputs you don't want to process:

```
$('[id^="q_"]').each(function(){if ($(this).val() == '') alert("Your Message Here");});
```

Comment: Thanks Mate... I combined yours and titus ode:                      $(this).before("missing text") and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery (and using jQuery would be easier):

```
foreach(i = 0, i<20, i++)
{
  if (document.getElementById('q_' + i).length == 0) {
    alert('box ' + i + 'is empty!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this pseudocode? What do you think the `length` property represents?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsById('q_'+i)[0].value.length > 0
```

in a for loop ought to roughly do it.

(though dropping [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) into your project would probably be a better plan)

Then you could iterate over a class. i.e.

```
foreach(i = 0, i<20, i++)
{
<input type = "Text" id="q_i" class="q">
}
```

and in your Javascript:

```
$("q").each(function(index,object){
  if(object.value().length <= 0) alert('empty!');
});
```

Comment: That selector is missing a "."

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://pastebin.com/ewVf0vPr) is a basic form validation that might be what you're looking for
It uses an invisible error message that shows up when you leave an empty field after you push the button. It doesn't accept white spaces. You can validate it multiple times and it behaves as expected
Here's the jquery part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("button").click(function()
                {   $('span[id^=q_]').addClass("hidden");
                    $('input[id^=q_]').each(function()
                    {if ($(this).val().replace(/ /g,'') == '') 
                        {   $("#"+$(this).attr('id')).removeClass("hidden");
                        }
                }); 
                });
 });
```

html part:

```
<style>.hidden{display:none;}
       .visible{display:block;}
</style>
<span id="q_1" class="hidden">Missing text</span>
<input type = "Text" id="q_1">
```

Not very pretty but it does the job